# How do I connect my flutter app to Power BI so that I get a BI dashboard report from the data retrieved from flutter app?

Tags: firebase, flutter, powerbi, dashboard

I have made a flutter app which lets users order food in the cafe, I want to use the data and make a BI dashboard report using a web app for the café manager so that he/she could view the total revenue, popular dishes, weekly or monthly sales etc. Please help

Comment: There is no connector for firebase, you should maybe look at Google Data studio to connect and visualize your data.

Answer (score 0):

I spent quite a lot of time trying to figure out how to add a PowerBI report to my web app. Now I figured out an easy way to do it with WebViewX package. I know this is a late answer since the question was asked last year but if you are still looking for the answer then follow the steps below.

1. Go to your PowerBI report and click on File->Embed Report->Website or Portal

[image]

2. Copy the iframe link shown in the popup dialog box as shown below.

[image]

3. Import WebViewX package from pub.dev and do the following

Firstly, initialize the controller

```
late WebViewXController webViewController;
```

and add the WebViewX widget with the iframe you copied from PowerBI

```
Expanded(
  child: WebViewX(
    initialContent:
        '<iframe title="PowerBITest - Page 1" width="100%" height="${size.height - 100}" src="https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=22168d3a-f9b7-4fee-843c-81cd38df3e1b&autoAuth=true&ctid=6b61b229-6177-49c2-9e92-caa8fd2f4f7f&config=eyJjbHVzdGVyVXJsIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93YWJpLXdlc3QtZXVyb3BlLWQtcHJpbWFyeS1yZWRpcmVjdC5hbmFseXNpcy53aW5kb3dzLm5ldC8ifQ%3D%3D" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>',
    initialSourceType: SourceType.html,
    onWebViewCreated: (controller) => webViewController = controller,
    width: size.width,
    height: size.height,
  ),
),
```

For the first time it will ask you to sign-in. Even though this solution is not 100% accurate, but it serves the purpose as of now!

Comment: For this, do we need a Microsoft Work account to do this? if no, what is the version of powerbi app thats prefferred, bcz 2.126.1261.0 64-b version does not have embed option available..

Comment: Yes, Microsoft Work Account is necessary. Embed option is only available with Pro license